# foreach to a link

Tags: php, html, foreach

I have a problem.
 I have written a web site where there are two PHP files where 1st contains variables and one array and next one contains next array with variables. Variables of second file are url adress. And now I need to know, if I can make something like:

with foreach

```
foreach($array01 as $word) {
    $a = 0;
    echo '<a href="'. $array_url[$a] .'><li>'.$word.'</li></a>';
    $a = $a + 1;``
}
```

Output:

```
<a href="var_url01"><li>var01</li></a>
<a href="var_url02"><li>var02</li></a>
```

with foreach:

```
foreach ($array01 as $word) {
    $a = 0;
    echo '<a href="'.$array_url[$a].'"><li>'.$word.'</li></a>';
    $a = $a + 1;
}
```

I know it does not works with this example but maybe there is a way to make it correct.

Comment: pardon.. my 1st topic..

Comment: Can you edit in what `$array01` looks like? What is `$array01 = ??`.

Comment: And `$a` will always reset to 0 for each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Move `$a = 0;` outside of `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you're doing `$a = 0;` at the beginning of each loop. That undoes the `$a = $a + 1;` that you do at the end, so you're using `$array_url[0]` every time. You can fix that by putting `$a = 0;` before the loop instead of inside it.

But instead, you can tell `foreach` to give you the array indexes as well as the values. Then you can use that index to access the other array.

```
foreach ($array01 as $i => $word) {
    echo '<a href="'. $array_url[$i] .'><li>'.$word.'</li></a>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your question is unclear, you must specify your arrays

**BUT**

i think you should use `for` instead of `foreach`

```
for($a=0; $a < count($array01); $a++)
{
    echo '<a href="'. $array_url[$a] .'><li>'.$array01[$a].'</li></a>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What your asking is unclear but as I've understood from your question, you want to take an array of urls from a PHP file into another PHP file and output them as link in the HTML format.

If that's the case then follow this:

Your 2nd PHP file should look like this as far as I can guess::

```
 <?php
     //some codes..
     $arrayofvariables=["word" => "url_address",....];  //your array of url address
     //some codes..
 ?>
```

And in your 1st file do something like this::

```
 <?php
     include 'pathtoyour2ndfile'; // include your 2nd file with url array
     foreach($arrayofurladdress as $word => $url_address){
           echo "<a href=\"$url_address\"><li>$word</li></a>";
     }
```

I could not figure what is the use of the variables and array in the first file. So, If this isn't what you're looking for please try to clarify your question by improving your English or upload all the content of your PHP files in the question.

Thanks. And A Happy New Year 2016. Hope my answer helps you. If it does don't forget to rate it and mark as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$a = 0;

foreach ($array01 as $word) {
  echo '<a href="'.$array_url[$a].'"><li>'.$word.'</li></a>';
  $a++;
}
```

if your `$array_url` is like

```
  $array_url = [ 'var_url01' , 'var_url02', 'var_url03'] ;
```

and your `$array01` is like
      $array01 = [ 'var01' , 'var02' , 'var03'];

then you can use the `foreach` loop as

```
foreach ($variable as $key => $value) {
    echo '<a href="'.$array_url[$key].'"><li>'.$word.'</li></a>';
}
```